# Start Application Before Windows Shell Starts Up?

Tags: windows

I have an application that I'd like to startup/display before the Windows Explorer shell comes up.

I basically want my application to be the first thing to load after login. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to do this.

Comment: Belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: Your edits make it more generic, but I would still say it belongs on SO.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is to make your application the windows shell and then run explorer.exe from you application.

Try changing the shell value in the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Change it to start your application instead of starting explorer.exe.

Answer (score 4):

Logon scripts execute before the shell is loaded.  You could call your application from within a logon script.  The logon script could be specified either in the local policy of the computer, or in the user's properties (both AD user accounts or local user accounts can have a logon script).

If you want your application to execute before even logon scripts have been run, you will need to replace the path to *userinit.exe* in the registry value:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit (REG_SZ)
```

Replace it with the path to your application, then make sure your application calls userinit, so that windows can proceed with running logon scripts and loading the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Run app as service. You have more than one way to do it